# Does the following have an analitical solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following equations:
\begin{equation}
{1\over f(x,y)} {\partial f(x,y) \over \partial x} \alpha(x,y)
+ {1\over f(x,y)} {\partial f(x,y) \over \partial y} \beta(x,y) = \gamma(x,y)
\end{equation}
Where $\alpha(x,y)$, $\beta(x,y)$ and $\gamma(x,y)$ are exactly known functions. What I need to find is $f(x,y)$. Can anyone help me find a solution? Or are there any assumptions (other than $f(x,y) = g(x)h(y)$ that will allow me to solve this analytically? Is it a standard equation that I haven't come across? If no analytical solution exists can it be solved numerically - if so how would I go about doing that?